# Html.BeginForm renders the Controller name twice

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm rendering a form in my view using `Html.BeginForm`, but I'm having some issues -- and I'm pretty sure this has worked in production for a year or so...

To render my form I 've written this, in my MVC view using Razor:

```
@{ Html.BeginForm("SaveProduct", "Main", FormMethod.Post); }
```

but, it gets rendered to the DOM with the controller name twice, like so:

```
<form action="/Main/Main/SaveProduct" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
```

According to the docs I've read it should be working correctly with the params I'm using, so I'm lost on how I should approach this issue. Does anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: Are you inside an area ? That code looks fine to me. What is the current page you are in ?

Comment: The url to the page is `/products/edit`. Although, I realize, this view is rendered from the `ProductController` and not the `MainController`. Could there be something there?

Comment: Are you sure that is the code which is generating that html output ? I see `novalidate` attribute on the generated output , but do not see that in your c# code

Comment: Yes, that's the correct code. If I delete/edit it, the change is shown in the DOM.

Comment: **I'm pretty sure this has worked in production for a year or so** So how is not working all of a sudden ?

Comment: Share your RouteConfig code (usually inside the ~/App_Start/RouteConfig.cs file).

Comment: @Shyju, `novalidate="novalidate"` is added by `jquery.validate.js` to prevent HTML5 validation.